# Probability with Discrete Random Variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with $P\{X = i\} = ci$ for positive,
odd integers $i ≤ 11$; otherwise, the probability is zero. Compute the value of
$c$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For a [discrete random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution) we must have: $$P(X=1)+P(X=3)+P(X=5)+P(X=7)+P(X=9)+P(X=11)=1$$